# Titles not showing on links or nodes using JS D3.js Version 3

Tags: d3.js, title

This is currently the code looks like however I seem to be unable to print the metric/weight on the network links or the network title on the nodes. If someone could help out that would be great. if you'd like to see the network diagram please send it over a message. I'm using D3.js version 3.

Below is my code:

```
var width = 1000, height = 700;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg")
if (svg.empty()) {
 svg = d3.select("#d3-example").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);
}

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
 links = graph.links

var nodes = {};
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.1)
    .linkDistance(200)
    .on('tick', tick)
    .charge(-1000)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');

link.append("text")
    .attr("class", "data text-tooltip1")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "Black")
    .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" +
            ((d.source.y + d.target.y)/2) + "," + 
            ((d.source.x + d.target.x)/2) + ")";
    })   

    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.target.name);
         return d.target.name;
    });

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', width * 0.02)

node.append("svg:title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });

function tick(e) {

    node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
};
})
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the relevant parts and tell us why you are "unable to print the metric/weight"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below modifications in your code. This should solve your problem:

```
var width = 1000, height = 700;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("#d3-example").select("svg")
if (svg.empty()) {
 svg = d3.select("#d3-example").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height);
}

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
 links = graph.links

var nodes = {};
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
        });

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.1)
    .linkDistance(200)
    .on('tick', tick)
    .charge(-1000)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link').attr('id', function(d){return d.id});

d3.selectAll(".link").each(function(d) {

        svg
            .append('svg:text').attr("class", "LinkLabelText")
            .style("font-size", 15)
            .style("fill", "teal")
            .attr("x", (this.getTotalLength() / 2))
            .attr("y", "-20")
            .append('textPath')
            .attr("xlink:href", "#" + d.id)
            .html(function() {
                return d.target.name;
            });
    });

    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        console.log(d.target.name);
         return d.target.name;
    });

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', width * 0.02)

node.append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });

function tick(e) {

    node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });
};
})
```